# Tests with test fixtures as class methods (PyTest)

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, fixtures, test-class

In organising tests in `PyTest`, I have seen that the test methods can be defined within a test class, like so:

```
class TestBasicEquality:
    def test_a_equals_b(self):
        assert 'a' == 'b'
```

If we want to write a test (`test_client`) that has to use a PyTest fixture `client` we do something like this:

```
def test_client(client):
    # assert client.something == something
```

But how can we organise the `test_client` within a test class? I have tried using `@pytest.mark.usefixtures(client)` as a decorator for the test class with no success.

Can someone show how and/or point to a guide/documentation for me to understand?

And perhaps **a question hidden behind all this**: when should we (or shouldn't) put pytest tests within a class? (only now starting to learn PyTest..) ?

Comment: Your decorator is incorrect, the argument should be strings, so it should be: `@pytest.mark.usefixtures("client")`  as explained [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#usefixtures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your given case you would simply include the fixture as another method argument:

```py
class TestSomething:
    def test_client(self, client):
        assert client.something == "something"
```

So what are the classes good for? Personally, I rarely have a need to use them with pytest but you can for example use them to:

1. Make groups of tests within one file and be able to run only one group: `pytest ./tests/test.py::TestSomething`
2. Execute a fixture for each test method while the methods don't necessarily need to access the fixture itself. An [example from the documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#using-fixtures-from-classes-modules-or-projects) is an automatic clean-up before each method. That is the `@pytest.mark.usefixtures()` that you have discovered.
3. Have a fixture that is [automatically](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#autouse-fixtures-xunit-setup-on-steroids) run once for every test class by defining a fixture's [scope](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#scope-sharing-a-fixture-instance-across-tests-in-a-class-module-or-session) to `class`: `@pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)`

Comment: This does not actually answer the problem the OP had.  The op had incorrectly used the decorator (Interesting that they didn't get a type error)

Comment: @RufusVS OP demonstrated that he/she knows how to use a fixture in a test function but wanted to use it within a test class method instead. `@pytest.mark.usefixtures()` wouldn't allow OP to easily access `client` fixture/object inside the method.